# Efficient way to iterate through a very large csv file with integers?

Tags: java, csv

Input 1: A .csv file with a long list of integers. Ex:

```
1
10
23
2450
12
560
320
705
...
```

Input 2: A .csv file with a list of integers, and a blank position next to each integer

```
5 -
12 - 
15 -
13 -
350 -
```

Output: Find the count of integers from input 1 that the input 2 integer is greater than or equal to and append the number into the .csv file.

The catch is that this involves DNA sequencing, and input 1 has over a million data entries. What would be an efficient way to approach this problem?

My thoughts were to read in all entries of input 1 into one large array and sort it, but that seems both inefficient and requires a lot of memory. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Output (same file as input 2):

int, count

```
5 1
12 3
15 3
13 3
350 5
```

Comment: if input 2 is much smaller, then store the integers from input 2 in memory, sort them, and for each int from input 1, take the next greater integer from input 2 and add 1 to count. At the end, for each integer `x` in input 2 you have the count of numbers, that lie between the previos and `x`. To have all smaller number then `x`, just sum all previous counts. This requiries only memory of input 2 and only linear time regarding input 1, which, as I understand, is much longer.

Comment: I don't see any commas in your "csv" files.  Aren't they just text files?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Please can you show an example of the output?

Comment: Do you mean to say "the *corresponding* input 2 integer is greater than [...]"?

Comment: When you say "insert the number into the .csv file" do you mean *append* the number to one of the input files? Append it to a different file?  Or what?

Comment: @AndyTurner essentially, find the count of the integers in input 2 that are <= input 1 integer

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I added in some edits and added a sample output for the data I provided. Yes, I meant append.

Comment: A million records is not that big to not be able to load into the memory. If that is still not possible you can try to split Input1  into multiple files and process them separately. You can utilize Hadoop for example where your key is each number in Input2 and the reducer values are counts of number that are smaller than your key.

Answer (score 0):

Put the numbers from the second file into a sorted map, with a value zero:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<>();
for (Integer i : fromFile2) {
  counts.put(i, 0);
}
```

Then, for each number your read from the first file, increment the counts up to that number:

```
for (Integer i : fromFile1) {
  counts.headMap(i).replaceAll((k, v) -> v + 1);
}
```

Note that this second loop doesn't require you to read the entire file into memory: you can just read them one at a time.

Also, note that `headMap(i)` returns entries with keys strictly less than `i`. Assuming `i < Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you can simply add 1 to that value.

Comment: You can even improve on this a bit.  For each value read from input 1, you need only increment the recorded count for the *first* element of input 2 that is at least as large.  On output of each item, add up the counts of that item and all lesser ones.  This improves the asymptotic complexity unless the size of input 2 is bounded by a constant, in which case it still reduces the coefficient.